# Hashing and Salting using c# with a database in Access

Tags: c#, hash

Hello guys i'm looking to learn how to hash and salt passwords in c# using a database in microsoft access, searching through google I couldn't find much information or tutorials about it, so if anyone could point me in the right direction on how this is done or link me to a tutorial this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hashing and salting a password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103717/hashing-and-salting-a-password-field)

Comment: Hashing/Salting methods do not change between data storage types, so any tutorial on this methodology can do what you are asking for. Possibly look into how to do data manipulation between c# and MS-Access and Hashing/Salting in different places.